# A segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c, artificial-intelligence

I am currently working on this project for school, where I am implementing an algorithm to find a solution for the 'knight game' (it's about finding the shortest way from the top left corner of the board to the bottom right corner), but I've been getting this segmentation fault for three days now, I've checked every pointer I used and everything seems right. 
I implemented " searching algorithms, bfs and dfs and ucs, the first two ones work fine, but ucs gives me the segmentation fault, even though they use the same thing except a popBest function. 
Here are some pictures of the ucs and popBest function:

```
Item *popBest( list_t *list ) // and remove the best board from the list.
{
  assert(list);
  assert(list->numElements);

  int min_f;

  Item *item = list->first;
  Item *best;
  min_f = list->first->f;

  while (item) {
    if (item->f < min_f) {
      min_f = item->f;
      best = item;
    }
    item = item->next;
  }
  //item = onList(list, board);
  delList(list, best);

  return best;
}

void ucs(void)
{
    Item *cur_node, *child_p, *temp;

    while ( listCount(&openList_p) ) { /* While items are on the open list 
        printLt(openList_p );
        /* Get the first item on the open list*/
        cur_node = popBest(&openList_p);
        //printf("%d  %f\n", listCount(&openList_p), evaluateBoard( cur_node ));
        printBoard(cur_node);

        addFirst(&closedList_p, cur_node);

        if ( evaluateBoard(cur_node) == 0.0 ) {
            showSolution(cur_node);
            printf("\nParcours en largeur (bfs)\n" );
            return;
       }
       else {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BOARD; i++) {
                child_p = getChildBoard( cur_node, i );

                if (child_p != NULL) {
                    child_p->f = cur_node->f+1;
                    temp = onList(&openList_p, child_p->board);
                    if (temp ==NULL) addLast( &openList_p, temp);
                    else if (temp != NULL && child_p->f < temp->f )
                    {
                        delList(&openList_p, temp);
                        addLast( &openList_p, temp);
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }

    return;
}
```

All  the functions work fine for bfs and dfs, the only difference is the popBest function.

Comment: Please turn your code quote into a [mcve]. If you do that right you will probably find the answer on the way.

Comment: I almost fixed the bad code comments (unmatched `/*` to `//`), but perhaps that is in your actual code, so you should really verify that first, then paste your *actual code* to the question (also make it MCVE).

Comment: I will do, thanks a lot.

Comment: no it's not mine, I wan editing it while writing the question and I didn't notice when posting the code. Thanks

Comment: best is if you run the code you post here and check that it reproduces your actual problem. If your real code needs some edits before you can post it here, then online compilers can be very handy to create a mcve. For example here the code does not compile (hence no segfault) : https://wandbox.org/permlink/zXaRHdLhidqXyhNo

Comment: Yes it wouldn't compile as I didn't post the whole code, otherways it would be very very long, Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You do `list->first->f` without checking whether `list->first` is the null pointer.

The cause of your problem is probably that `best` is potentially uninitialised after the loop, and it will definitely be if the first element in the list is "best".

Here is a safer version.

```
Item *popBest( list_t *list )
{
  assert(list);
  assert(list->numElements);
  assert(list->first);

  // Assume that the first element is best.
  Item *best = list->first;
  int min_f = best->f;

  // Search from the second element (if it exists).
  Item* item = best->next;
  while (item) {
    if (item->f < min_f) {
      min_f = item->f;
      best = item;
    }
    item = item->next;
  }
  delList(list, best);
  return best;
}
```

Comment: `list->first` should always exist if IIUC that that is implied by `list->numElements != 0`. But that `best` would be uninitialized if the first element is best already is a good observation. In your example though It seems to be 0 in a list with a single element (where `best->next` is 0 for `best == first`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment,

Comment: actually the listCount function assures that the list in not empty (contains an Item none NULL), when I compile it prints out the first board with the knight in top meaning that it does pop up the first element, but it gives a segmentation fault after.